# How does Vuex 4 createStore() work internally

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vuejs3, vuex4

I am having some difficulty understanding how Veux 4 `createStore()` works.

In `/store/index.js` I have (amongst a few other things):

```
export function createVuexStore(){
   return createStore({
            modules: {
                userStore,
                productStore
            }
      })
}

export function provideStore(store) {
provide('vuex-store', store)
```

}

In `client-entry.js` I pass the store to `makeApp()` like this:

```
import * as vuexStore from './store/index.js';
import makeApp from './main.js'
const _vuexStore = vuexStore.createVuexStore();

const {app, router} = makeApp({
    vuexStore: _vuexStore,
});
```

And `main.js` default method does this:

```
export default function(args) {
    const rootComponent = {
        render: () => h(App),
        components: { App },
        setup() {
            vuexStore.provideStore(args.vuexStore)
        }
    }

    const app = (isSSR ? createSSRApp : createApp)(rootComponent);
    app.use(args.vuexStore);
```

So, there is no `store` that is exported from anywhere which means that I cannot import `store` in another `.js` file like my `vue-router` and access the `getters` or `dispatch` actions.

```
import {store} '../store/index.js' // not possible
```

In order to make this work, I did the following in the `vue-router.js` file which *works* but I don't understand why it works:

```
import * as vuexStore from '../store/index.js'
const $store = vuexStore.createVuexStore();

async function testMe(to, from, next) {
   $store.getters('getUser'); // returns info correctly
   $store.dispatch('logout'); // this works fine
}
```

Does Veux's `createStore()` method create a fresh new store each time or is it a reference to the same store that was created in `client-entry.js`? It appears it is the latter, so does that mean an application only has one store no matter how many times you run `createStore()`? Why, then, does running `createStore()` not overwrite the existing store and initialise it with blank values?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`createStore()` method can be used on your setup method.

On your `main.js`, you could do something like this

```js
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import store from './store'

createApp(App).use(store).use(router).mount('#app')
```

`store.js`

```js
import { createStore } from 'vuex';

export default createStore({
  state: {},
  mutations: {},
  actions: {},
});
```

To access your store, you don't need to import `store.js` anymore, you could just use the new `useStore()` method to create the object. You can directly access your store using it just as usual.
`your-component.js`

```js
<script>
import { computed } from "vue";
import { useStore } from "vuex";

export default {
  setup() {
    const store = useStore();

    const isAuthenticated = computed(() => store.state.isAuthenticated);
    const logout = () => store.dispatch("logout");
    return { isAuthenticated, logout };
  },
};
</script>
```

To use your `store` in the `route.js` file, you could simply imported the old fashion way.
`route.js`

```js
import Home from '../views/Home.vue'
import store from '../store/'

const logout = () => {
  store.dispatch("auth/logout");
}

export const routes = [
  {
    path: '/',
    name: 'Home',
    component: Home
  }
]
```

Comment: Your example is about using `store` in a .vue Component.  I need to use it in `vue-router.js` which is a `.js` file not a `.vue` Component, so `{useStore}` does not work in that situation.

Comment: Yes, `useStore()` only works on the `setup()` method, but you can always import the store manually. I have updated my answer.

Comment: `createStore` doesn't have `state, mutations, getters, actions` to export. It creates a store from modules in the code see: `return createStore({ modules: {userStore, productStore } })`

Comment: Yes.... that's just the same... `createStore` can use the module system, but can work independently without modules system. I use the module system on my project. I don't get what is your current problem now? You can simply import your store from your router.

Comment: I think we are talking about the same thing, but I am getting confused as to what `export deafult createStore({})` is doing. When you `import store from '../store/'` is it running the `createStore()` method again and creating a NEW store? If it creates a new store, how come the store isn't empty upon creation?

Comment: export default is a javascript way to export something that you can use over and over on another file. It did not create a new store. It references to that store. You can read about export more here. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export

Comment: Accepted as answer. After following your guidance, I managed to figure it out and it works! Thank you Kevin

Comment: I have a similar question, can you guys help me to check it? Thanks. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72514359/how-to-mutate-the-vuex-through-js-file?noredirect=1#comment128098645_72514359